# Dojo Datagrid Sort after adding New Item to Store

Tags: sorting, datagrid, dojo

I'm having an issue with a DataGrid not resorting itself after calling newItem() then save() on the store backing the datagrid.

```
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" url="/MultiRaterManagerAjax" id="mrWriteStore" jsId="mrWriteStore"</div>     

<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" region="left" query="{ hasSub: false }"
        clientSort="true" selectionMode="single"   jsId="ldrSubGrid" sortInfo="1"
        errorMessage="Loading..." store="mrWriteStore">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th width="100%" field="_item" formatter="formatSubs">Subs</th>     
              </tr>

          </thead>
</table>
```

An event handler calls the following javascript

```
item = mrWriteStore.newItem({});
//set the necessary attributes on item
mrWriteStore.save({onComplete:afterStoreUpdate, onError: saveFailed});
```

A new item is added to the store, and the DataGrid is updated showing the new item. But the new item is at the bottom of the list. It doesn't seem to recognize the sorting order of the datagrid.

I'm thinking there is an event I need to connect to (or subscribe to) on the datagrid which tells me it has updated the data. Then I call sort/filter functions when this event is fired. But what to connect/subscribe to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with this the other day. I think you need to call the sort() method of the datagrid from inside of your onComplete function, which you have named afterStoreUpdate

```
dijit.byId('ldrSubGrid').sort();
```

Comment: This is working for sorting. Thanks. I didn't think an event on the store would be what I want for sorting on the grid. Still having an issue with filtering in the same circumstance, but I don't know enough to ask a question yet. onComplete: ldrSubGrid.filter({ hasSub: false,},null); isn't doing anything, yet that same code run after the fact in Firebug properly filters the grid. JavaScript is so wonky sometimes.

Comment: Is it wrapped in a function like this? onComplete: function() {ldrSubGrid.filter({ hasSub: false,},null); }   just checking to make sure