# Dojo DataGrid 1.6 not sorting after item inserted into the store

Tags: datagrid, dojo

There is a similar question asked here: [Dojo Datagrid Sort after adding New Item to Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541075/dojo-datagrid-sort-after-adding-new-item-to-store)
However I cannot seem to apply the solution suggested there, nor can I add my question to the accepted answer since I do not have reputation yet.

My jsfiddle example is pretty straight forward.  I am unable to sort after adding new item to the store. 
If somebody could please take a look it would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/mmlitvin/bh48f8d3/3/

Here is the full snippet of code:

```
debugger;
dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
dojo.require("dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore");
dojo.require("dojo.parser");

dojo.ready(function() {
    dojo.parser.parse();

    var data = {
        identifier: 'id',
        items: [
            { id:1, col1: false, col2: 'Sally', col3: 45},
            { id:3, col1: false, col2: 'Mary', col3: 98},
            { id:5, col1: true,  col2: 'James', col3: 33},
            { id:6, col1: true,  col2: 'Chris', col3: 72},
            { id:4, col1: false, col2: 'Laura', col3: 12},

        ]
    };

    var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});

    dijit.byId("grid").setStore(store);
    //dijit.byId("grid")._refresh();  

    //add new item
    dijit.byId("grid").store.newItem(
              { id:2, col1: true,  col2: 'Tom', col3: 23});

   //sort - attempt 1
    dijit.byId("grid").store.save ({
            onComplete:function(){ 
                dijit.byId("grid").sort();
                dijit.byId("grid")._refresh();
                console.debug("Sort invoked");
           }
     });

    //sort - attempt 2
    dijit.byId("grid").store.save();    
    dijit.byId("grid").sort();
    dijit.byId("grid")._refresh();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying which column to sort by.

```
//sort - attempt 1
dijit.byId("grid").store.save ({
        onComplete:function(){ 
            // add this to tell the grid to sort on the first column
            dijit.byId("grid").set('sortInfo', 1);

            dijit.byId("grid").sort();
            dijit.byId("grid")._refresh();
            console.debug("Sort invoked");
       }
 });
```